# Error with bootmer and confint for glmer

Tags: r, lme4, statistics-bootstrap

I'm running into an error that I can't find any documentation on when I try to bootstrap a `glmer` object:

```
glm2 <- glmer(RT~valence+location+first_location+Trial_num + 
                      (1+Trial_num|id)+(1|Trial_num), 
                      family=inverse.gaussian(log), 
                      control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap",
                                      calc.derivs = FALSE), data=df_long)
```

The error is:

> Error in lme4::.simulateFun(object = ,  : 
>     could not find function "sfun

This is regardless of whether I try `bootMer` or `confint`:

```
bootMer_out <- bootMer(glm2,FUN=fixef, nsim=300)

confint_out <- confint(glm2, method="boot")
```

When I run as an `lmer` object I don't have the issue with bootstrapping. i.e.

```
lm2 <- glmer(RT~valence+location+first_location+Trial_num + (1+Trial_num|id)+(1|Trial_num), family=inverse.gaussian(log), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE), data=df_long))
```

Does it have to do with the link function? Is there a workaround? I couldn't find function 'sfun' in the simulateFun documentation either. I could always just do the transformation on the data separately and use lmer instead of glmer, but if anyone has some insight that would be great (since I'm curious now).

Comment: `lme4::.simulateFun` leads to `lme4:::simfunList` , and so it looks like you will need to write a `simfunList$inverse,gaussian` method for `inverse.gaussian` family, which you might get from `inverse.gaussian()$simulate`

Comment: . I didnt see where to grab the dispersion parameter from, and ah, i seems this has been tried.. https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/predict.R#L776

Comment: You might try the `merTools` package to generate predicted values and distributions of parameters. It was built, in part, to address this issue -- though the results are not identical to what would be achieved by a boostrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @user20650, you'll need to add a simulation method for the inverse gaussian family.

For example, I added these to a branch on my lme4 fork under [predict.R](https://github.com/aforren1/lme4/blob/add_invgauss_simulate/R/predict.R#L787):

```r
rinvgauss <- function(n, mu, lambda) {
    # transcribed from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution
    nu <- rnorm(n)
    y <- nu^2
    x <- mu + (mu^2 * y)/(2*lambda) - (mu/(2*lambda)) * sqrt(4*mu*lambda*y + mu^2*y^2)
    z <- runif(n)
    ifelse(z <= mu/(mu + x), x, mu^2/x)
}

inverse.gaussian_simfun <- function(object, nsim, ftd = fitted(object),
                                    wts = weights(object)) {
    if (any(wts != 1)) message("using weights as inverse variances")
    dispersion <- sum((weights(object, 'working') * 
        resid(object, 'working')^2)[weights(object, 'working')>0])/df.residual(object)
    rinvgauss(nsim * length(ftd), mu = ftd, 
                     lambda = wts/dispersion)
}
# ... skip a few
simfunList <- list(gaussian = gaussian_simfun,
       binomial = binomial_simfun,
       poisson  = poisson_simfun,
       Gamma    = Gamma_simfun,
       negative.binomial = negative.binomial_simfun,
       inverse.gaussian = inverse.gaussian_simfun)
```

Here's an example:

```r
# devtools::install_github('aforren1/lme4', ref = 'add_invgauss_simulate')
library(lme4)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(y = lme4:::rinvgauss(1000, 3, 4),
                  x = runif(1000), 
                  subj = factor(rep(1:10, 100)))

mod <- glmer(y ~ x + (1|subj), 
             data = dat, 
             family = inverse.gaussian(link='log'))

# ~60 secs on my laptop
(boots <- confint(mod, method = 'boot', nsim = 100, parm = 'beta_')) 
                 2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept)  1.0044813 1.248774
x           -0.2158155 0.161213

(walds <- confint(mod, method = 'Wald', parm = 'beta_'))
                2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)  1.000688 1.2289971
x           -0.205546 0.1644621
```

You can see that the bootstrap method gives (roughly) the same results as the Wald method.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you point to a reference where the dispersion parameter is estimated by the within-unit error please. Sorry if this is obvious, but I couldnt find anything.

Comment: @user20650 maybe [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016-1/giner-smyth.pdf) on page 2 to start? They have `φ = σ^2`. It *think* it's also on pg. 30 of [Generalized Linear Models](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0412317605) by McCullagh and Nelder. It seems a popular parameterization is `λ = 1/(σ^2)`.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the statmod ref (shamefully I dont have the McCullagh book): I had messed about with an example from statmod earlier (part of the reason of my question): `x = rinvgauss(1e6, mean = 1.5, dispersion = 0.7)` . This seems to give the dispersion parameter in the univariate case. `var(x) / (mean(x)^3)`. And running a basic glm: `summary(m <- glm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars, family=inverse.gaussian))` seems to illustrate that the dispersion 
parameter is not equal to the `sigma(m)^2` / var(y|x). Both kind of started me thinking that the within random error may not be quite correct.

Comment: I don't have it either, the Google Books preview ended up having it though. What about `sigma(glm(mpg ~ 1, data=mtcars, family=inverse.gaussian))^2` vs `var(mtcars$mpg)/(mean(mtcars$mpg)^3)` as a simple case? They're pretty close (unless I've misunderstood altogether).

Comment: @user20650 I'm pretty sure you're right, I've updated it to calculate the dispersion like `glm` does.

Comment: Interesting. Did you have to dive into the c_code to find this?

Comment: Much more superficial -- it's in the first few lines of `stats::summary.glm`. The only necessary change was ensuring that working weights/residuals were used.

Comment: Thanks. I hadnt realised that the dispersion parameter wasnt estimated in the optimisation. Goes back to your earlier comments of reading books!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had a chance to implement because I'm running into github issues, but looks like a straightforward solution.

Comment: @MikaelRubin ; if you are having issues with github you can just edit simfunList from lme4.